# Regular expression to take value between brackets "()"?

Tags: php, regex

I am very poor in writing regular expression.

I am trying to get value between brackets "()". Something like below...

```
$a = "POLYGON((1 1,2 2,3 3,1 1))";
preg_match_all("/\((.*)\)/U", $a, $pat_array);
print_r($pat_array);
```

But this will give me  elements like...

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => ((1 1,2 2,3 3,1 1)
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => (1 1,2 2,3 3,1 1
        )
)
```

But i want to fetch "1 1,2 2,3 3,1 1" as a output.

I know we can trim the brackets after getting this output. But this will be great if it done using Regular Expression.

Thanks in advance.

---

**Solution:** as per **@anubhava** answer:

Using **@anubhava**'s regular expression.

**Example:**

```
$a = "POLYGON((1 1,2 2,3 3,1 1),(1 1,2 2,3 3,1 1),(1 1,2 2,3 3,1 1))";
```

And if print result of this regular expression you will get like this...

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => ((1 1,2 2,3 3,1 1)
            [1] => (1 1,2 2,3 3,1 1)
            [2] => (1 1,2 2,3 3,1 1))
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1 1,2 2,3 3,1 1
            [1] => 1 1,2 2,3 3,1 1
            [2] => 1 1,2 2,3 3,1 1
        )
)
```

Look at second array element, it's exactly like we want.

**FYI: I have used it for Fetching GEOMETRY Data of POLYGON from MySQL Database and then i processed it with array to get all Latitude and Longitude of all Polygon Nodes.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use negation based regex pattern and get your result from captured group #1:

```
preg_match_all('/\(+([^()]*)\)+/', $a, $pat_array);
print_r($pat_array[1]);
```

`[^()]*` will match any char that is not `(` or `)`.

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1 1,2 2,3 3,1 1
)
```

Comment: It work's very well as i expected. I don't know the meaning of your regualr expression but it worked for me. Thank you.

Comment: I have written a brief explanation in my answer for my regex. Let me know if you have any specific question about it.

Comment: What is + at the end for ?

Comment: @Palo That is to match multiple `)` in the end.

Comment: Yes but is it needed? Because match always starts at `(` .

Comment: Ok I just wanted to know if I am missing something here, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use `lookarounds`

```
preg_match_all("/(?<=\()[^()]*(?=\))/U", $a, $pat_array);
```

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/vV1wW6/42

Comment: No, that's not working. it gives me "(1 1,2 2,3 3,1 1" as output.